# How to invoke fragment method from activity when I use FragmentPagerAdapter to add fragment into activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio-3.0

I create three fragment for swipe view on `MainActivity`. That's why I use `FragmentPagerAdapter` to add those fragments on `MainActivity`. It's all working well. Now I create the bellow method on fragment one.

```
public void myToast(String text){
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

How I can call/invoke this method from `MainActivity`?

Note : I can't use `findFragmentById()` or `findFragmentByTag()` method because There are no `id` and `tag` for those fragments.

Comment: when do you want to call this method?

Comment: are your fragments in a `ViewPager`?

Comment: Yes my fragments in 'ViewPager'.

Comment: If your application stops, there must be a stack trace. it'd be helpful if you posted it

Answer (score 1):

you can use these methods -

```
private static String makeFragmentName(int viewPagerId, int index) {
        return "android:switcher:" + viewPagerId + ":" + index;
    }
```

And to access -

```
YourFragment yourfragment = (YourFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(makeFragmentName(yourpager.getId(),the fragment number must be int /* 0, 1, 2 *\));
```

then you can use the method of your fragment in activity-

```
yourfragment.maketoast()
```

Comment: I used this formula. But when I use `yourfragment.maketoast()`, the application just stop!

Comment: I know friend. I am new but not a fool. I cast my fragment properly like your example. But when I invoke fragment method the application just stop!

Comment: `fragment_one f_one = (fragment_one) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(makeFragmentName(my_view_pager.getId(),0));`

Comment: I write like this. I am using **Android Studio**. If I copy paste your code. The studio will show me wrong.

Comment: **Android Studio** don't show any problem. It also create **apk** file of my project. I test my project in my mobile. After install the **apk** file when I open the app my mobile show alert **unfortunately app stop** .

Comment: Check the logcat in Android studio when the app unfortunately stopped